# Как открыть более одного окна через for?

Tags: c, c++

Существует программа, которая после закрытия открывает одно окно в dev-c++ через команду

```
system("start http://google.ru");
```

Как открыть более одного окна, через условие for? Полный нуб, помогите, пожалуйста, в этом.

**Перенесено из комментария.**

```
/* 
 * Copyright ©
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#define PI 3.1415

main()
{
    // cor do cmd (verde)
    system("color 2");
    // variaveis decimais
    float circu, perim, raio, area;
    int i;

    if (circu <= 0) {
        printf("O numero que indicou esta invalido!");
    } else {
        printf("Insira o diametro da circunferencia: ");
        scanf("%f", &circu);
        // ...
    }
    // pause
    system("PAUSE");
    for (size_t i = 0, i < 100, ++i) {
        system("start http://google.ru");
    }
}
```

Выдает ошибку, работа в dev - c++ (c)

Comment: Какие именно ошибки выдает? Мы не экстрасенсы.


- Во первых, в с++ функция main должна возвращать int.
- Во вторых, у вас в коде определено 2 переменные с одним именем i.
- В третьих, троеточие тоже нужно убрать.

Comment: Добавьте в начале 

     #include <cstdlib>
     using namespace std;

Comment: В цикле for должны быть не запятые, а точки с запятой. При этом в самом ответе всё правильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наверно так. По идее откроет 10 окон.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
    { 
        system("start http://google.ru"); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: а зачем для цикла size_t? почему не выбрал int?

Comment: Проверил в MinGW, все работает правильно.

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.